# how to remove a charater from a string (python)

Tags: python, character

I have a text file that contain a bunch of websites.

```
text = '"wadouri:https:\/\/dev.pluginslab.com\/dicomviewer\/wp-content\/plugins\/pl-dicom-viewer-amazon-s3\/assets\/cases\/8255\/20191209113141\/sagittal-00000001.dcm","wadouri:https:\/\/dev.pluginslab.com\/dicomviewer\/wp-content\/plugins\/pl-dicom-viewer-amazon-s3\/assets\/cases\/8255\/20191209113141\/sagittal-00000002.dcm","wadouri:https:\/\/dev.pluginslab.com\/dicomviewer\/wp-content\/plugins\/pl-dicom-viewer-amazon-s3\/assets\/cases\/8255\/20191209113141\/sagittal-00000003.dcm", etc'
```

I was able to extract each website into a list

However there are '/' character in my list I cant seem to remove.

could some one tell me where I got it wrong

Thanks

```
import re
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import os

myfile = open('C:/test/test.txt', 'r')

regex  = re.compile(r'(?<=https).*?(?=dcm)')

dcm =[]
for line in myfile:
    matches = regex.findall(line)
    for m in matches:
        dcm.append (str('https' + m + 'dcm'))

for d in dcm:
    d.replace('/','')
    print(d)
```

Comment: you arent printing the modified string. use: `print(d.replace('/',''))` or `d = d.replace('/','')`

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? It's a JavaScript library, and has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove forward slashes? More likely it's the backslashes you want to remove. I'm not sure why you're getting them, unless this is a JSON file. But if it's JSON, you should be using the `json` module to parse it, not do your own string processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` returns the replaced string. Check the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace)

You can use

```
for d in dcm:
    new_string = d.replace('/','')
    print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the output of `d.replace('/','')` into a new variable like this:

```
for d in dcm:
    new_string = d.replace('/','')
    print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable in Python, therefore you have to create a new string.

Position based replacement:

```
d = d[:pos] + d[(pos+1):]
```

Character based replacement:

```
d = d.replace('/','')
```

then to see new string

```
print(d)
```